# Full status information in Nagios email notification?

Tags: email, configuration, nagios, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

I have set up Nagios to monitor my servers and I have written a few custion checks.

When I get a notification email, I only get the first line of the status information and I have to use the web interface to see the rest of it.

Is it possible to get the full status information in the email ? How would I configure that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhere in your NAGIOS config, you should have a definition of the command used to send email notifications.  If it's anything like mine, this will say

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-service-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }
```

If you change that `Additional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$"` in the code that generates the body of the email to say `Additional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$` you should get all the lines of your service output, not just the first.  Check  your NAGIOS doco on host macros for more things you might want to include.